# Make a resource schema dependant on another variable

Tags: go, terraform

I'm creating a plugin in Terraform and I want to add a field to the schema which can be called only when another field has been provided.

```golang
    "host_name": &schema.Schema{
        Type:        schema.TypeString,
        Optional:    true,
        DefaultFunc: schema.EnvDefaultFunc("host_name", nil),
        Description: "Should give name in FQDN if being used for DNS puposes .",
    },
    "enableDns": &schema.Schema{
       Type:        schema.TypeString,
       Required:    true,
       DefaultFunc: schema.EnvDefaultFunc("host_name", nil),
       Description: "Should give name in FQDN if being used for DNS puposes .",
```

Here I want to pass the `enableDns` string in the `.tf` file only when `host_name` is passed. If it is not given and I pass `enableDns` it should throw an error during plan.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform providers don't really have a first class way to do stuff conditionally based on other parameters other than the `ConflictsWith` attribute.

There is a hacky way to do some cross parameter stuff using `CustomizeDiff` but it's only really used in a couple of places where it's really needed.

Normally the provider would simply validate the individual parameters and if the API that the provider is working against requires cross parameter validation then this is only seen at apply time when the API returns the error.

For an example of using `CustomizeDiff` to throw a plan time error when doing cross parameter validation see [the `aws_elasticache_cluster` resource](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_elasticache_cluster.go#L242-252):

```
    CustomizeDiff: customdiff.Sequence(
        func(diff *schema.ResourceDiff, v interface{}) error {
            // Plan time validation for az_mode
            // InvalidParameterCombination: Must specify at least two cache nodes in order to specify AZ Mode of 'cross-az'.
            if v, ok := diff.GetOk("az_mode"); !ok || v.(string) != elasticache.AZModeCrossAz {
                return nil
            }
            if v, ok := diff.GetOk("num_cache_nodes"); !ok || v.(int) != 1 {
                return nil
            }
            return errors.New(`az_mode "cross-az" is not supported with num_cache_nodes = 1`)
        },
```

Comment: Isn't this CustomizeDiff function would be only called when an existing resource is going to updated with new values?