# How can I write a ValidateFunc for 2 fields of Terraform provider schema?

Tags: terraform

I am writing a custom provider in which I have 2 fields defined in the schema namely : host_instance_type and storage_capacity. What is the best way to write a validation function for storage_capacity whose behavior is different for different host_instance_type ? 
In this the storage_capacity, must be specified only for a specific host_instance_type (say A). But storage_capacity should not be specified for a host_instance_type (say B).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958813/2291321 answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValidateFunc`, unfortunately, only takes the field on which it's defined as an argument.

You can, however, perform validation logic in the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) logic of the resource itself, however. For example, see how AWS' lambda function resource performs validation in its "Create" function: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_lambda_function.go#L297

Comment: It's worth noting that this validation will only happen at `apply` time rather than at plan/validate time like a normal `ValidateFunc` will.

Comment: It would have been great if Terraform could perform validate between two different fields so that the error can be returned on terraform plan rather than apply.

Comment: @SaloneeRege one common solution, though not a direct answer to your question, is just use different blocks per config type rather than a key that discriminates the type (with certain properties). For example, see the sub-blocks under `logs_configs` here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html